# Axios POST works but axios.create POST generate 400 Bad Request Error

Tags: post, cors, http-headers, axios, preflight

Frontend framework: React JS

Backend framework: Python Flask

Before, I was using a proxy in package.json `"proxy": "https://www.thehostofmyapi.com:6444"` (because I'm connected in SSH to my work's remote server) and I was making calls without an axios instance, see below:

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.post('/api/checks', {foo: 'bar'})
  .then(response => console.log(response));
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

everything was working fine and I was POSTing/GETing my data.

Now, I've created an axios instance:

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: '/api',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },

  transformRequest: [data => keysToCase(data, snakeCase)],
  responseEncoding: 'utf8',

  validateStatus: status => status === 200 || status === 201,
});
```

Everything works fine when I'm making GET requests, but when I'm making a POST, I'm getting a 400 Bad Request Error.

Below, the response I get in the browser

```
data: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">↵<title>400 Bad Request</title>↵<h1>Bad Request</h1>↵<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>↵"
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"

headers:
  access-control-allow-origin: "https://www.thehostofmyapi.com:6444"
  connection: "close"
  content-length: "192"
  content-type: "text/html"
  date: "Fri, 27 Dec 2019 09:20:52 GMT"
  server: "Werkzeug/0.16.0 Python/3.6.9"
  vary: "Origin, Accept-Encoding"
  x-powered-by: "Express"

config:
  url: "/api/checks"
  method: "post"
  data: {mission_id: "5df27777c85c4b639d4862ca"}
  headers:
  Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
  Content-Type: "application/json"

transformRequest: [ƒ]
transformResponse: [ƒ]
timeout: 0
adapter: ƒ xhrAdapter(config)
xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN"
xsrfHeaderName: "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
maxContentLength: -1
validateStatus: status => status === 200 || status === 201

request: XMLHttpRequest
onreadystatechange: ƒ handleLoad()
readyState: 4
timeout: 0
withCredentials: false
upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload {onloadstart: null, onprogress: null, onabort: null, onerror: null, onload: null, …}
responseURL: "http://localhost:3000/api/checks"
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
responseType: ""
response: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">↵<title>400 Bad Request</title>↵<h1>Bad Request</h1>↵<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>↵"
responseText: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">↵<title>400 Bad Request</title>↵<h1>Bad Request</h1>↵<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>↵"
responseXML: null
onloadstart: null
onprogress: null
onabort: ƒ handleAbort()
onerror: ƒ handleError()
onload: null
ontimeout: ƒ handleTimeout()
onloadend: null
```

Two noticeable behaviors:

1. When I put `baseURL: 'https://www.thehostofmyapi.com/api'` in the `axios.create` and remove the proxy in package.json:

I get a 400 but notice an OPTION request appears in the server's logs

2. When I keep the proxy in package.json and put `baseURL: '/api'`

I still get a 400 but notice no OPTION request in the server's logs

I heard about Preflighted requests, (what apparently the OPTION call is) but how come everything works when I'm not using `axios.create`? and how could I fix this?

Comment: thats not the way to show a error `.then(err => console.error(err));` this is the way `.catch(err => console.log(err));`

Comment: I know, just a typo. sorry about that

Comment: Is there any stack trace in python backend when you get thee bad request (Status 400) error, can you share that?

Comment: All I have is that

`INFO:werkzeug:10.138.7.214 - - [27/Dec/2019 09:29:37] "POST /checks HTTP/1.1" 400 -`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. I just got rid of the `transformRequest` and passed its function to `axiosInstance.interceptors.request`

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: '/api',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },

  responseEncoding: 'utf8',

  validateStatus: status => status === 200 || status === 201,
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  config => ({
    ...config,
    data: keysToCase(config.data, snakeCase),
  }),
  error => error,
);
```